# When switching to another doc, Function Argument window disappears?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup, arguments

I have problem with Excel 2007 when using VLOOKUP function. After switching to another document for referencing value in "Table_array" field, window dissapears.
Google finds some results about the problem, but nothing helpful.
Following things have already been considered:

- Security problems (Trusted center is OK, settings too)
- File locations (excel spreadsheets are in the same folder)
- Cells are numbers, not text

Answer (score 1):

when you start typing the formula into the first window `=vlookup(.......` you must type your first paramater `=vlookup(firstparameter ....` then make sure to type the comma `,` ..... after you have typed the comma, you can now go to your other window and freely select the next parameter